# about $n$-th power equation with integer coefficient of roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

first i'm sorry for my terrible english

my question is

$n$-th($n>1$) equation with integer coefficient has $p+qi$ ($p$ is irrational and $q$ is real)

then $-p+qi$ is also root of this equation (not complex conjugate!!)

ex)

4th equation $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ ($a,b,c,d$ are intergers)

has root $2\sqrt2 + di$ ($d$ is not $0$)

that the all roots of $f(x)=0$ is $\pm2\sqrt2 \pm di$

how to proof general case?($n>1$)

thanks

Comment: You may want to look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Say I have an equation $x^3 = 2$, do its complex roots satisfy your claim?

Comment: The complex conjugate $\overline{-p+qi} = -p-qi$. If the function $f$ is even, then $f(-x) = f(x)$, then $\pm p\pm qi$ are all roots if one of them is.

Comment: to.peterwhy  nono..!  suppose equation has p+qi(p is irrational, q is real)

Comment: The roots of $x^3=2$ are $\sqrt[3]2$ and $$\sqrt[3]2\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}3 \pm i\sin\frac{2\pi}3\right) = \frac{\sqrt[3]2}2 \pm \frac{\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt[3]2}2i$$
Is $\frac{\sqrt[3]2}2$ not irrational or $\frac{\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt[3]2}2$ not real?

Comment: to.peterwhy  oh thanks understand. my mistake. and fixed the claim n is even interger(>1) and so on. thus this claim is true?

Comment: What about the roots of $x(x^3-2) = 0$?

Comment: thanks! if guaranteed n-th equation(n>1) has root forms p+qi(p is irr- q is real) with at least 4 complex roots. then +-p +-qi is also roots of equation? or counter example?

Comment: edit. 4th eqaution f(x)=0 with integer coefficient. and one of roots is p+qi(p is irr- q is real(not 0)  let k=p+qi and degree of irr(k,Z[x])=4 then +-p+-qi are also roots of eqaution?

Comment: @EndofEternity I am getting confused by your edits. Can you edit your question instead?

Comment: new questions are here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748178/about-nth-eqaution-with-integer-coefficients-of-roots

Comment: @EndofEternity Do you know you can edit your question?